# Overall Rollup Process [RB.1.5]

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

In Sequencing Pseudo Code and at line "3.2. Apply the appropriate Objective Rollup Process to the activity" of "Overall Rollup Process [RB.1.5]", I don't know which Objective Rollup Process I should apply (i.e., Using Measure or Using Rules or Default Rules).

Please explain for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing a SCORM 2004 sequencing engine,
and just started implementing [RB.1.5]. At first I was
confused at the same point too. But finally I reached
the following conclusions:

- The term, "**appropriate**", that confuses you is pointless.
- "Objective Rollup Process" in [RB.1.5] merely references [RB.1.2 b].
- The **appropriate** objective rollup process will be selected
  and applied in [RB.1.2 b].

Lines from 1. to 1.2. in [RB.1.2 b] determines whether the
default rollup rules should be applied or not. The rest of
the code is for objective rollup using rules process.

Comment: I don't see any 'line 1.2' in [RB.1.2 b]. Do you mean that we don't need [RB.1.2 a]?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I missed [RB.1.2 a]. I'll post an update version of my answer considering [RB.1.2 a] soon. Hold on a moment, please ;)

Comment: By the way, did you see the version 1.1 of 4th ed.? I'm sure that [RB 1.2 b] of 4th ed. Version 1.1 contains line 1.2. I'll continue answering on the assumption that your target version is 4th ed. Version 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code does not define how to select **the appropriate Objective Rollup Process** in [RB.1.5].
Instead, section 4.6.5. of the SN book states how to do that.

Here is a summary of the section, translated into Ruby pseudo code:

```
if activity.rolled_up_objective.objective_satisfied_by_measure == true
    apply_objective_rollup_process_using_measure
elsif activity.rollup_rules.any? { |rollup_rule| [:satisfied, :not_satisfied].include?(rollup_rule.action) }
    apply_objective_rollup_process_using_rules
else
    apply_objective_rollup_process_using_default_rules
end
```

In the version 1.1 of SCORM 2004 4th Edition,
both Objective Rollup Process Using Rules
and Objective Rollup Process Using Default Rules are included into [RB.1.2 b],
so line 3.2. of [RB.1.5],

```
Apply the appropriate Objective Rollup Process to the activity
```

should be:

```
For each objective associated with the activity
    If Objective Contributes to Rollup for the objective is True Then
        Set the rolled-up objective to the objective
        Break For
    End If
End For
If (the rolled-up objective is Defined) And (Objective Satisfied By Measure for the rolled-up objective is True)
    Apply the Objective Rollup Using Measure Process [RB.1.2 a] to the activity
Else
    Apply the Objective Rollup Using Rules Process [RB.1.2 b] to the activity
End
```